# Different people like different things - how to say it in a more informal way?

Tags: expressions, idiom-request

I am translating a text, and I should be as precise as possible. I am wondering whether there exists such an expression 'who likes what' (it sounds weird to me) meaning 'different people like different things' or 'taste differs'? What do native speakers say that could be close to my 'who likes what' ('one likes different things')?

It does sound weird but I am trying :-)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Different strokes for different folks? One man's meat is another man's poison? Tastes differ?

Comment: Each to his own? Love it or hate it? There have got to be more and some will be context specific, such as food or clothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Who likes what

is a question in English and does not mean the statement that

> Different people like different things.

It might be asked at an informal dinner party where there are many different dishes to eat, and the server wants to know which each person wants. Although it is not very striking, the second example highlighted above is perfectly clear, grammatical, and idiomatic.

Michael Harvey's comment gives several examples in U.S. English of **standard** expressions that express the thought.

> Tastes differ

is the most concise, but perhaps a bit formal.

> One man's meat is another's poison

is traditional, but a trifle informal and perhaps a bit old-fashioned as is

> Some like it hot; some like it cold, and some like it in the pot, nine days old.

As for

> Different strokes for different folks

it may be considered vulgar and is frequently used in a somewhat disparaging way.

There are probably additional traditional phrases to express a thought that is universally valid.

Comment: I think that "One man's meat is another's poison" is a humorous corruption of "One man's meat is another's poisson", French for "fish".

Comment: @ Peter That would be really funny if historically accurate. Not sure that I care: it is a shame to ruin a good story with potential facts.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

- Everyone's different
- Everyone has different tastes in (noun)
- Tastes differ
- That's not my cup of tea